# Clarification on merging 2 linked lists with a dummy node (problem with return statement)

Tags: python-3.x, merge, linked-list

I have this working code, but I don't understand the return statement. What is `head` supposed to be pointing to? It has `-1` as value and its `next` would be None. So wouldn't we get `None` as a return? I need some clarification please.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        head=ListNode(-1)
        dummy_head=head
        while l1 is not None and l2 is not None:
            if l1.val<l2.val:
                dummy_head.next=l1
                l1=l1.next
                dummy_head=dummy_head.next

            else:
                dummy_head.next=l2
                l2=l2.next
                dummy_head=dummy_head.next

        if l1!=None:
            dummy_head.next=l1
        if l2!=None:
            dummy_head.next=l2
        return head.next
```

Comment: At some point you are settings `dummy_head.next`, which is `head.next`, so it's not None anymore

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I assume that returning head.next would point to dummy_head, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Try to take a notebook and sketch a single example run. See that summy_head is advanced in the `while` loop, right? But head itself isn't, it stays as a placeholder for the actual head of the list, while dummy_head is the one that advances